# Square integers and palindromic

Tags: calculus

I have a big problem with this exercice:

We calculate the sum of squared integers : $0^2+1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+...$
We must stop the sum when : 
a)we add the square of a palindromic number (being at least two figures)

b)and the sum is itself a palindromic number
Can you help me find this number ?

Thanks

Romain

Comment: Consider the integers in increasing order and "palindromize" them (make sure that you obtain the palindromes in increasing order as well). For each evaluate the sum of the squares by the Faulhaber formula, and check their "palindromicity".

Comment: Mathematica says that the first value is 181, with the sum of squares 1992991.

Comment: What does mean the part a), please? It is not that the sum is the square of a palindromic? (in whose case, Catalin Zara's answer is not correct because $1992991$ is not even a square).

Comment: I read it as saying that the last term we add is $n^2$, with $n$ a palindrome ("we stop when we add the square of a palindromic number ...")

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the "brute-force" method.**

---

Let $f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}n^2=(2n^3+3n^2+n)/6$, then:

- $f(11)=506$
- $f(22)=3795$
- $f(33)=12529$
- $f(44)=29370$
- $f(55)=56980$
- $f(66)=98021$
- $f(77)=155155$
- $f(88)=231044$
- $f(99)=328350$
- $f(101)=348551$
- $f(111)=462056$
- $f(121)=597861$
- $f(131)=757966$
- $f(141)=944371$
- $f(151)=1159076$
- $f(161)=1404081$
- $f(171)=1681386$
- $f(181)=1992991$

Comment: @Arthur: Correct. And I am unable to think of an efficient (non-exhaustive-search) manner for tackling this problem. Perhaps we should search for a value of $n$ such that $(2n^2+3n+1)/6$ is divisible by $11$, but I'm not too sure about this.

Comment: Not that every palindrome is divisible by eleven.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, only the ones with an even number of digits...

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica says that the first value is 181, with the sum of squares 1992991.

[Added] Mathematica also says that if we use base $m$, then the only pairs $(n,m)$ with $m$-palindromic multi-digit $n$ such that $1^2+\dotsb + n^2$ is also $m$-palindromic and $2\leq m \leq 20$, $3 \leq n \leq 1000000$ are $(5,4), (17, 4), (25, 4), (85,7), (60,9), (546,9), (4920,9), (44286, 9), (398580,9), (398580,9)$, and $(181, 10)$.

The examples with $m=9$ can be explained as follows: Let 
$$n=6\cdot 9^0+6\cdot 9^1 + \dotsb + 6\cdot 9^k = 6\cdot \frac{9^{k+1}-1}{9-1},$$ 
with $k=2, ..., 7$. Then
$$1^2+2^2+ \dotsb + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{(9^{k+1}-1)(9^{2k+3}-1)}{(9-1)^2} = (1+9+9^2+ \dotsb + 9^{k})(1+9+\dotsb + 9^{2k+2}) = 1 + 2\cdot 9 + 3\cdot 9^2 + \dotsb + (k+1)9^{k} + (k+1) 9^{k+1} + \dotsb + (k+1)9^{2k+2} + k 9^{2k+3} + \dotsb + 2 \cdot 9^{3k+1} + 9^{3k+2}.$$

Comment: I value, however, the honesty of having quoted Mathematica. Recently someone gave an answer that had used a calculator but without citing it.

Comment: I agree that Mathematica deserves the credit, not me. On the other hand, it does provide an answer - though not a detailed solution ...